# How can i create correct line breaks in a sns sms message?

Tags: c#, .net-core, amazon-sns, aws-sdk-net

I'm using the **AWS .NET-SDK** for sending SMS messages with the **AWS SNS service**. So far, so good; but when I use line breaks, I see the `?` char at this point before the line break begins in the SMS. After that character, the line break is added as expected. Is there any possibility to get a line break without this `?` character?

I have also tried following:

- `StringBuilder.AppendLine`,
- `"\\n"`,
- `"\\r\\n"`,
- `@"\n"`,
- `@"\r\n"`,
- `Environment.NewLine`

And encoding the string into UTF-8.

Example which doesn't work:

```cs
// Create message string
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("Line1.");
sb.Append("Line2.\\n");
sb.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);
sb.Append(@"Line4\n");

// Encode into UTF-8
var utf8 = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
var stringBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
var decodedString = utf8.GetString(stringBytes);
var message = decodedString;

// Create request
var publishRequest = new PublishRequest
{
    PhoneNumber = "+491234567890",
    Message = message,
    Subject = "subject",
    MessageAttributes = "Promotional"
};

// Send SMS
var response = await snsClient.PublishAsync("topic", message, "subject");
```

Comment: Remove *all* the UTF8 related code. .NET strings are UTF16 already.

Comment: That i have already attempt before i tried the UTF8 stuff. The encoding had made no diffenrence.

Comment: *Remove* any attempts at encoding to begin with. It *does* make a difference. Maybe not with `\n` and `\r` as they are part of US-ASCII, but it will definitely mangle any non-English character and many special characters like `£`, `¦` or `¤`.

Comment: I was able to send multiline messages without any kind of encoding. The question's code doesn't use `publishRequest` though while `MessageAttributes` is a dictionary, not a string

Comment: yes you are right, my mistake. I had paste the wrong publish-method. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove all attempts to encode the string. .NET strings are Unicode, specifically UTF16 already. `PublishAsync` expects a .NET string, not UTF8 bytes.

As for why this error occurs, it's because the code converts the string into bytes using the *local machine's codepage* and then tries to read those bytes as if they were UTF8, which they aren't - using UTF8 as a system codepage is a beta feature on Windows 10 which breaks a *lot* of applications.

The newline character for SMS is `\n`. `Environment.NewLine` returns `\r\n` unless you use .NET Core on Linux. [StringBuilder.AppendLine](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Text/StringBuilder.cs#L996) uses `Environment.NewLine` so you can't use it.

You shouldn't need anything more than String.Join to combine multiple lines into a single message:

```
var message=String.Join("\n",lines);
```

If you need to use a StringBuilder, use `AppendFormat` to append a line with the `\n` character at the end, eg :

```
builder.AppendFormat("{0}\n",line);
```

**Update**

I was able to send an SMS containing newlines with this code:

```
var region = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1;
var  snsClient = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(region);

var sb = new StringBuilder()
                .Append("Line1.\n")
                .Append("Line2.\n")
                .Append("Line4\n");
var message = sb.ToString();

// Create request
var publishRequest = new PublishRequest
{
    PhoneNumber = phone,
    Message = message,                
};

// Send SMS
var response = await snsClient.PublishAsync(publishRequest);
```

The message I received contained :

```
Line1.
Line2.
Line4.
```

I decided to get fancy and changed the last line to :

```
.Append("Line4ΑΒΓ£§¶\n");
```

I received this text without problems too